# APEX 5: Make a report cell clickable and pass values

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

Just got started on APEX 5 and can't seem to figure out how to make cells in an Interactive Report clickable. What I'm trying to achieve is something like this:

Let's say I have a report on Page 1:

[image]

I want to be able to click on any cell in Column 2 and 3, and it should open a new page and show a list of items that made up that number, something like this:

[image]

I understand how dynamic actions work and how I can pass values but I just can't figure out how I can hyperlink or make the cells clickable, to set up any dynamic actions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make the Column Type a Link and under Link Attributes, define the target page and set the items or filter report accordingly. You can have the Link Text as #COLUMN_NAME#.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will find this post useful

http://www.grassroots-oracle.com/2015/12/tutorial-include-action-button-in-report.html

but most of the time you should start with a very declarative looking link builder, once you change the column Type to "Link"

[image]